# Inserir nó lista ligada

Tags: c

tenho essa função de inserir no inicio, mas não estou conseguindo testá-la.
Segue:

```
void inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
 novo_no -> prox = p;
 p = novo_no;
}
```

Quero identificar o erro desta função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tipo_lista * inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
 novo_no -> prox = p;
 return novo_no;
}
```

O novo_no agora será o primeiro elemento, basta retorna-lo.
Quando você chamar a função, sua lista deve receber o retorno da função.

Ex:

```
p =  tipo_lista inserir_inicio (p, novo_no);
```

Comment: Aqui não deu certo não.

Comment: Estava faltando `*` no tipo de retorno da função, já corrigi. Agora está tipo_lista *.

Answer (score 0):

```
void inserir_inicio(tipo_lista *p, tipo_lista *novo_no){
    novo_no->prox = &(*p);
    *p = *novo_no;
}
```

Ao que me parece, você se esqueceu de fazer a **desreferenciação** do ponteiro p. Uma das formas como gosto de analisar os parâmetros de funções é vê-los como se fossem variáveis declaradas implicitamente dentro da função. Por exemplo, no seu caso, você espera o endereço de uma variável tipo_lista para modificá-lo usando um ponteiro chamado `p`. Mas você se esqueceu que p é uma variável local da função inserir_inicio, portanto quando você diz `p = novo_no` você está modificando *a variável local, não a variável alvo.* Por isso você **desreferencia** p e novo_no: Para dizer que você quer modificar e obter os endereços de memória deles, respectivamente.

Comment: E como chamo na função?