# Função inserir em lista

Tags: c

Olá. Estou desenvolvendo essa função abaixo:

```
void inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
  novo_no -> prox = p;
  p = novo_no;
}
```

E na `main` estou chamando:

```
inserir_inicio(&p, cria_no(1));
imprimir_lista(p);
```

E quando executo não sai nada na tela.

Alguém saberia me dizer se a função inserir_inicio está errada?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Inserir nó lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200408/inserir-n%c3%b3-lista-ligada)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No main sua função começa vazia(NULL), então você chama a função de inserir e não atualiza o valor do main, então a lista continua vazia. Caso a lista não seja vazia, você vai inserir no começo e não vai atualizar no main qual é o primeiro, então o erro continua.

O que está faltando é o return:

```
tipo_lista * inserir_inicio (tipo_lista * p, tipo_lista * novo_no)
{
  novo_no -> prox = p;
  return novo_no;
}
```

E no main:

```
p = inserir_inicio(p, cria_no(1));
imprimir_lista(p);
```

Comment: Então mas quero testar com `void`

Comment: E com esse `&` deu erro Programa parou de funcionar.

Comment: Por que você quer testar com void?